# How to get the active/current/selected range on every sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Let's say I have two sheets - `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`. One has cell `B2` selected in the UI of Google Sheets, another has `C3` selected.

How to get the selected cell on every sheet with google apps script?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)  See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Comment: My experience is that you cannot get the active/current/selected cells in other sheets and if you try to change the active sheet programmatically then that action seems to set the current cell to A1.  Perhaps other people will have more information than I.  I also wonder why Ruben voted down and closed.  I was going to ask about what you did but I assumed that you tried several ways like I have in the past.  There seem to be several limitations to the spreadsheet ui that would have made them much nicer for building games with. This and the ability to detect intersections would have been good.

Comment: hahaha spent two hours  - is this the reason to downvote and close??

Comment: If you have found something in those two hours, post it in your question, especially what didn't work. The tested mcve code, the expected  result and the actual result. I agree with the down vote. The downvote button clearly says the reason for downvoting is "Doesn't show research"(The downvote currently present is not mine though). I do not agree with the close vote and can't speak for the reasoning of the voter

Comment: Don't let the  two hours spent go to waste. Share your research and code. Someone who wants to try can pick up from where you left off, instead of spending extra two hours like you to get to the same point.

Comment: @vstepaniuk SO is very far from a nice site, but I happily gave the last undel vote to your question. But only after rollbacking to the penultimate version... (P.s. Get a f...g refugee visa in the EU!!! We all welcome you!!!) Note, excel sorcery might be a better match on the https://superuser.com .

Comment: @peterh How did you find this question?

Comment: @TheMaster With the 10k+ tools, I regularly check questions to undelete and I do if they deserve.

Comment: `My experience is that you cannot get the active/current/selected cells in other sheets and if you try to change the active sheet programmatically then that action seems to set the current cell to A1.` Agree 100% with @Cooper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know sometimes its useful give a 2nd look to things... Thank you @peterh for reopening my question.

Anyway I have a simple and elegant solution to this question - one can use named ranges to track the active range

First create manually named ranges for each sheet you want to track and call them for example `Sheet1act`, `Sheet2act`, where `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` are the actual sheet names. If you ever rename the sheets you'll need to rename the tracking ranges manually.

```
// on change of selection update the tracking range
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  
  // the name of the active sheet
  var eSheetName = e.range.getSheet().getName();
  
  Logger.log(eSheetName);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));

  var namedRanges = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getNamedRanges();
  
  // set active range to the tracking named range for the active sheet
  for (var i = 0; i < namedRanges.length; i++) {
    var nr = namedRanges[i];
    if ( nr.getName() === eSheetName+'act' ) {
      nr.setRange(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange());
    }
  }
}

// on Open set tracking ranges to A1 - since they keep their previous value because position hasn't been changed yet
function onOpen() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // all named ranges in the spreadsheet
  var namedRanges = ss.getNamedRanges();

  // generate an array of sheet names
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheetNames = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sheetNames.push(sheets[i].getName() + 'act');
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < namedRanges.length; i++) {
    var nr = namedRanges[i];
    // check if this is a tracking named range
    if ( sheetNames.includes( nr.getName() )) {
      // set a range of this named range to A1 on its sheet
      nr.setRange( nr.getRange().getSheet().getRange('A1') );
    }
  }
}
```

Takes about a second to update

Works even with Google Sheets mobile apps